# create Query Builder symfony inner join

Tags: mysql, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

could anyone please convert this sql query into query builder in symfony.

```
Select a.* From article a 
Inner Join 
  articles_devis ad On a.id=ad.article_id 
Inner Join 
  devis d On d.id=ad.devis_id 
Inner Join 
  utilisateurs u On u.id=d.user_id 
Where u.id=7 and Where  d.id=63
```

I have tried this line code but it didn't work

```
public function ArticlesByDevisByUser(){
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
                ->select('a.*')
                ->from('ArticleBundle:Article', 'a')
                ->innerJoin('a.articledevis', 'ad')
                ->where('articles.id = ad.article')
                ->innerJoin('ad.devis', 'd')
                ->where('d.id = ad.devis')
                ->innerJoin('d.user', 'u')
                ->where('u.id = d.user')
                ->andWhere('u.user=7')
                ->andWhere('d.id=63');
        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
```

Comment: "didn't work" : did it crash ? what is the error ? is it not the expected result? please elaborate a bit

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a Repository and link it to your Article using `@ORM\Entity` annotation (in case it is not already done) :

In your Article entity :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="YourProject\YourBundle\Entity\ArticleRepository")
 *
 */
class Article
{
...
}
```

And then in your ArticleRepository put your function :

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class ArticleRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function ArticlesByDevisByUser($userId, $devisId)
    {
       return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
           ->innerJoin('a.articledevis', 'ad')
           ->innerJoin('a.devis', 'ad')
           ->innerJoin('a.user', 'au')
           ->where('ad.id = :devisId')
           ->andWhere('au.id = :userId')
           ->setParameter('userId', $userId)
           ->setParameter('devisId', $devisId)
           ->getQuery()
           ->getResult();
    }
}
```

I put `articledevis`, `devis` and `user` for the `innerJoin` but it depends attributes names you give in your `Article` entity